# java.util.Set, but with custom constraint on field

Tags: java, collections

I wonder if there is a nice way to have Set on objects, but constrained on custom fields.

For example I need a `Set` of POJO's:

```
class MyPojo {
  private String name;
  private Map<Object, Object> stuff;
  //getters, setters, constructor
}
```

And I want to have a `Set` where they will be unique by name.
I could implement `hash` and `equals` based on `name` property, but then I can't use really `equals` to compare them.

Is there some nice workaround or maybe Guava/apache commons collection for this?

Comment: Does this compile   private Map<Object> stuff; ?

Comment: Can you use a custom comparater then, when you want to compare them? Otherwise would a `HashMap` keyed on `name` be appropriate?

Comment: @JunedAhsan yep, fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create wrapper objects. It's like a decorator pattern. You wrap your original object with different hash implementations and then wrapped object will be used in the Set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HashMap<String,MyPojo>` instead of a `Set<MyPojo>`. This way, each `name` can appear at most once in the `Map`.

Comment: Ok, but what if I want a composition of 2 fields? Then logic will be too bulky

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko If your key becomes composite, you should consider creating a separate class for the key - `MyPojoKey` or `MyPojoID` (which would override hashCode and equals) - and then use a `Map<MyPojoID,MyPojo>`.